# Text Field2 related to text1 field

Tags: force.com

In visualforce page ,I  want to show hidden text2 field , if text1 field is not null in visualforce page.

Comment: Have you already tried something ?

Answer (score 1):

1 way to achieve is:

step 1. on page load set style for text2 display :none

step 2. Write javascript on  the event onchange/onblur of text1  and check text1 is not null then set style for text2  display:block

Comment: If you post a sample code, it would be helpful for the questioner to dive deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You Can apply rendered condition in text2 field..

cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: give class to text2 text1 input feild 
Step2: on page load 
$('.text1Class').hide();
if($('.text1Class').val() !='') {
$('.text2Class').show();
}